# Efficient leave-one-out permutations from lists of items in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have the `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"id": [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                          "countrycode": ["GB", "US", "US", "GB"], 
                          "articleno": [["628897", "551515"], ["590448", "617953", "617953"], ["505372", "635892", "635891", "635895"], ["628822", "551551"]]})
```

`df`:

```
    id  countrycode articleno
0   1   GB          [628897, 551515]
1   2   US          [590448, 617953, 617953]
2   3   US          [505372, 635892, 635891, 635895]
3   4   GB          [628822, 551551]
```

and I would like to create all possible list-permutations from the `articleno`-column for each `id` (row), where the ordering has no meaning. To clarify: I consider the lists `[635892, 635891, 635895]` and `[635895, 635891, 635892]` identical, therefore only one of them should be created.

**Assumptions**:
**1.** The lists in `articleno` in `df` above always contain at least **two** items.
**2.** The items in the lists are not necessarily unique (look at `id`==2).

**Expected output:** (Since the ordering of the lists does not matter, multiple correct "Expected outputs" exist.)

```
    id  countrycode articleno                   target
0   1   GB          [628897]                    551515
1   1   GB          [551515]                    628897
2   2   US          [590448, 617953]            617953
3   2   US          [617953, 617953]            590448
4   3   US          [635892, 635891, 635895]    505372
5   3   US          [505372, 635891, 635895]    635892
6   3   US          [505372, 635892, 635895]    635891
7   3   US          [505372, 635892, 635891]    635895
8   4   GB          [628822]                    628822
9   4   GB          [551551]                    551551
```

The motivation behind this is to create permutated training data for a machine learning classification task. Because of immense data quantities, I am in need of an efficient solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your data structure, a list comprehension might be your best choice:

```
new_df = df.join(df.articleno.explode().rename('target'))

new_df['articleno'] = [[a for a in x if a != y] 
                       for x,y in zip(new_df['articleno'], new_df['target'])]
```

**Option 2**: double explode and query:

```
new_df = (df.join(df.articleno.explode().rename('target'))
            .reset_index(drop=True)
            .explode('articleno')
            .query('articleno != target')
            .groupby(level=0)
            .agg({'id':'first','countrycode':'first',
                  'articleno':list, 'target':'first'})
         )
```

**Option 3**: Similar to double explode, but self-join:

```
new_df = df.explode('articleno')

(new_df.join(new_df['articleno'].rename('target'))
    .query('articleno != target')
    .groupby(['id','target'], as_index=False)
    .agg({'countrycode':'first','articleno':list, })
    
)
```

Output:

```
   id countrycode                 articleno  target
0   1          GB                  [551515]  628897
0   1          GB                  [628897]  551515
1   2          US          [617953, 617953]  590448
1   2          US                  [590448]  617953
1   2          US                  [590448]  617953
2   3          US  [635892, 635891, 635895]  505372
2   3          US  [505372, 635891, 635895]  635892
2   3          US  [505372, 635892, 635895]  635891
2   3          US  [505372, 635892, 635891]  635895
3   4          GB                  [551551]  628822
3   4          GB                  [628822]  551551
```

Comment: Assuming all three options are interchangeable, do you know which one would be the most efficient for a `df` with a lot of rows (100s of thousands)?

Comment: I would recommend the third option